# Declaring template functions in a C++ interface?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, interface

For the sake of a demonstration imagine that I have some animal classes, each derived from an 'animal' class, each 'knowing' what type they are, and each having some sort of unique ability:

```
enum class animal_type { antelope, bear, cat };

class animal
{
};

class antelope : public animal
{
public:
    static const animal_type type = animal_type::antelope;
    void run() { std::cout << "antelope runs\n"; };
};

class bear : public animal
{
public:
    static const animal_type type = animal_type::bear;
    void roar() { std::cout << "bear roars\n"; };
};

class cat : public animal
{
public:
    static const animal_type type = animal_type::cat;
    void meow() { std::cout << "cat meows\n"; };
};
```

Now, I want to be able to retrieve animals based on their type:

```
class animal_getter
{
public:
    animal& get(animal_type t)
    {
        static antelope s_antelope;
        static bear s_bear;
        static cat s_cat;

        switch (t)
        {
            case animal_type::antelope:
                return s_antelope;

            case animal_type::bear:
                return s_bear;

            case animal_type::cat:
                return s_cat;
        }
    }
};
```

And finally, it would be nice to get the actual type of animal back, to make the calling syntax nicer:

```
template<typename T>
T& get()
{
    return static_cast<T&>(get(T::type));
}
```

Now I can write something like this:

```
animal_getter ag;
ag.get<antelope>().run();
```

rather than the wordier:

```
animal_getter ag;
static_cast<antelope&>(ag.get(animal_type::antelope)).run();
```

I hope there's nothing too unreasonable about that. But now I want to be able to unit test getting an animal, so ideally it will be possible to fake the animal_getter class (imagine the actual implementation accesses a database or something which you don't want in a unit test, hence the fake). So it would be nice to define an interface for 'animal getter' classes, and then create a fake that implements the interface. And here's the problem, **can this interface be written**? This isn't going to compile:

```
struct IAnimalGetter
{
    virtual template<typename T> T& get() = 0;
};
```

**Is it possible to rescue this idea** or can template functions never be declared a virtual for the purpose of defining an interface that includes them?

**If the idea is a non-starter, at what point did this start to go wrong?** Was it when the template function was written which does its own casting? Should I have stopped at something which returns an animal object and then have the caller be responsible for the cast?

Comment: It isn't quite clear why you need this. Just make your static data members public. `ag.get<antelope>().run()` does nothing `ag.s_antelope().run()` doesn't.

Comment: (continued) There are no virtual templates, so a virtual `get template` is not possible. You can get around this with the visitor pattern and/or ctrategicalky placed casts, but it still isn't clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. What does `get<antelope>()` buy you that `get_antelope()` doesn't?

Comment: Perhaps the error is having an empty base class if the derived classes have nothing in common? Needing casts or switching on the type are both signs of problems with the model. Surely antelopes aren't silent and bears can run.

Comment: Thanks all. The real code I'm working on is far more complicated than this - I just wanted to demonstrate the problem as simply as possible for the sake of brevity. Please don't take this example code as anything other than an illustration of what I'm trying to do, which is specifically to create a fake object based on an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual template functions are not allowed, but your template function has no logic, so in this case I would use:

```
struct IAnimalGetter
{
    virtual animal& get(animal_type t) = 0;

    template<typename T>
    T& get()
    {
      return static_cast<T&>(get(T::type));
    }
};
```

And:

```
class animal_getter : public IAnimalGetter
{
public:
    animal& get(animal_type t)
    {
        // implementation
    }
};

class mock_animal_getter : public IAnimalGetter
{
public:
    animal& get(animal_type t)
    {
        // mock implementation
    }
};
```

Comment: I had thought about this, but got a bit wrapped up about having an 'interface' not containing anything other than pure virtual functions. Quite nice to see someone championing this as a legit practice. Thanks.

Comment: Another option is provide a non-member template function. This will keep your interface pure, but will make your code less object-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

The use of casting kind of defeats the point of using templates here.
Its not really clear to me what the getter class is for. Its clear its for holding some static instances of some pre-determined types, but its not clear why its a single class handling all the types. I can't see that you gain much as it doesn't have much code in and you have to specify the type in the call anyway. The switch statement is a potential bug, if you add a new animal type it will still compile but the new type wont be handled in the switch and you get a run time error.

If you don't need static instances, just construct the correct type.

If you do need them then consider whether they should be managed by that type (i.e. bear has a method to get the bear instance). Another option (as has already been pointed out) is to expose the static instances of each type your getter holds.

If you don't want to manage the static instances in the related classes, consider having separate getters:

```
template<typename T>
struct IGetter
{
    virtual T Get() =0;
};

template<typename T>
struct RealGetter : public IGetter<T>
{
    static T item;
    virtual T Get()
    {
         return item;
    }
 };

template<typename T>
struct MockGetter : public IGetter<T>
{

   virtual T Get()
   {
     // some mock implementation
   }
};
```

Comment: Please don't read too much into the example code - it's there to demonstrate the principle, not be picked over. The actual questions are highlighted in bold - it's those I was really asking, using the code as a vehicle to demonstrate the problem I'm facing. In the real code I'm working on of course there is no static instances being held by a single class - they're actually business objects obtained from an in-memory database. The code here is stripped right back for the purposes of demonstration and isn't meant to be realistic.

Comment: I understand that it's simplified code, but I think your getter has been simplified so much it hides your intent. You title and bolded questions are still quite general so I think an answer involving a different class structure (without the casting) may be the best option, but exactly what you'd want is hard to tell from your example. Is there a reason a template per gettable class wouldn't fit your real requirements?

Comment: I'm working with legacy code. We have a monolithic class which acts as the gateway to generic business objects. You want one? Use the function provided by the monolith (sort of like the animal_getter in my example)! The code base is ancient and there would be no appetite to move this functionality into the individual types (bear, cat, cockroach). The template get function was a compromise to make the calling code cleaner (no casting), but it makes the definition of an interface tricky. Hence the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: So how about using something like I showed, implementing the inside of RealGetter using your monolithic legacy way? (not that I'd call it RealGetter) you get to call via an interface and can sub it for a mock in the tests.